# How can I add wall panels to file cabinet drawers?

Tags: cabinets

So we bought an Erik filing cabinet from Ikea which was pretty easy to assemble for the most part. However, it was only after everything was said and done that we realized the drawers had no 'walls' on the sides and the back. Well technically they're filing cabinets so they don't really need those walls but it's something we'd like to have as we plan on using one of the drawers to store non-file stuff like little boxes etc which *will* fall out the back or the side in its current state.

Can anyone recommend an easy diy to accomplish this?
This is what the drawers of the Erik file cabinet look like...

[image]

And this is what we'd like it to be...

[image]

We live in an apartment so we can't really use a saw or anything to cut up wood

Comment: A bit of wood and some screws would do the trick.

Comment: Or just dropping a box into the drawer... Maybe several boxes if you want partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ten years ago, I temporarily took some old corrugated cardboard from a cardboard box and cut it to fit with a fold over the top rail. It is still there doing the job.

[image]
*<sup>different Ikea product, same problem</sup>*

If you have access to a pair of scissors, an old cardboard box and maybe some adhesive tape (optional) - you too can be the envy of your neighbours and friends.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, it would have been a lot easier to do the opposite and have it look good.

Get some plastic sheets from local hardware store, cut to size with utility blade and adhere with glue. Paint to match color if desired.

User 1/4' sheet of plywood, and liquid nail (glue) to frame. Paint to match color if desired.

Get a tubby that fits close to size and drop it in place.